# Android SDK launch same instance of activity

Tags: android, android-activity, instance, launch

I need to launch the same instance of an activity even if the user goes back and forth with the navigation. The user navigates in a stack of different activies (A, B, C), but when he goes to one of these activities it will show the same instance of that activity (like a static activity) calling only onResume.

Comment: This is the default behavior of Activities. As long as you don't call finish(), the Activity will go into the "paused" state, then resume when it is called again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force your Activity to start up in onResume(). What you can do, however, is save your Activity's state to a Bundle in onPause() and onStop(). Then, in onStart() read this Bundle to get your Activity's state.

Comment: I believe Karim Varela means you can save the state in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState). Android will try its best to resume the Activity exactly as it was when its left (ie navigate to a new Activity, put into the background) but if it can't you have to ensure any and all values you need to make the Activity like it was are saved in the outState bundle. If you haven't already done so, you should read the docs on the Activity lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html Work with the lifecycle, don't try to circumvent it.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to this is to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` in the `Intent` you use with `startActivity()`.

However, this will call more than `onResume()`. At minimum, your activities will be called with `onRestart()` and `onStart()`, assuming that whatever was in the foreground took over the whole screen.